# Is it possible to limit the number of times a user can be added to the same field across different entries?

Tags: entries, users, structure, sections

I want to make it so that each user can only be assigned once to a specific field across all entries. For instance, let's say we have a bunch of teams. A user can only be on one team at a time. Once assigned to a team roster, they should not be available to assign to another team. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not come at it from a different angle and instead choose your team by editing the user? That way you can assign a team field to the user and restrict that field so that you can only pick the one team.

Then in your templates you can use [relations](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations) to link them all up.

Comment: Nice suggestion! I had already built out the solution the other way, and then was asked if I could limit the user to being on one team programmatically. I'll have to think about the ramifications of that to my front-end code, and it's definitely something to consider. Thanks!